# How to convert two list of lists into list of dictionary such that the first element comes from the first list and the second from the other list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-lists

Suppose I have two list of lists as follows:

```
List1=[[1,2],[3,4],[3,8]]

List2=[[1.2,2.4],[2.4,5.0],[4.5,6.0]]
```

How would I get the above as:

```
List3 = [{1:1.2,2:2.4},{3:2.4,4:5.0},{3:4.5,8:6.0}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
List3 = [dict(zip(*lsts)) for lsts in zip(List1, List2)]
```

Comment: Thanks@ Riccardo Bucco, it worked

Comment: @Tania_hussain Please upvote my answer if you think it is useful and/or mark it as accepted

Answer (score -1):

```
List1=[[1,2],[3,4],[3,8]]

List2=[[1.2,2.4],[2.4,5.0],[4.5,6.0]]

List3=[]

for i,e in enumerate(List1):
   List3.append(dict(zip(List1[i],List2[i])))

print(List3)
```